# Detect browser's autofill in autocomplete method of jquery

Tags: events, input, browser, jquery-ui-autocomplete, autofill

I want a autocomplete functionality for address, for which I am using Google map api under jquery's autocomplete() method.

It is working fine for me, but the issue is when user select address from browser's autofill option, autocomplete method taking it as an input and give an ajax call.

So how I can prevent ajax call if an input is from browser's autofill?

Here is my code:

```
$('#address').autocomplete({
        minLength: 7,
        source: function(request, response){

            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:au&address="+$('#address').val(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                              // stuff on success
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
           // stuff on focus of option
        },
        select: function(event, ui, data) {
            event.preventDefault();
           // stuff on selection of an option

        }
    });
```